# Reading sensor data to control model in model plugin

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I would like to read some sensor data (contact force and position) to control my robot in model plugin. However, it's really hard to find the way for me. I couldn't find any tutorial explaining robot control by sensor feedback in Gazebo standalone version. Is there any unified way to read sensor data (Position, velocity, acceleration, image and etc.) and to control a robot in its model plugin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5248/reading-sensor-data-to-control-model-in-model-plugin/) by [Wonyoung](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/279/wonyoung/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 37 on 2014-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How about these 2 tutorials ? They helped me to implement a basic obstacle avoiding robot recently.

-[1](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/control_robot/mobile_base_laser)

-[2](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.2/intermediate/control_model)

Also, you can check [API ref](http://gazebosim.org/api/2.0.0/index.html).

For example, you can use  this one to read velocity data from your robot.

> math::Vector3 GetRelativeLinearVel ()

---

Originally posted by [SpiderRico](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/605/spiderrico/) with karma: 18 on 2014-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wonyoung](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/279/wonyoung/) on 2014-01-17**:
Thank you for the kind answer! I don't know why I missed these ones. I have searched all wrong key words. By the way, it would be nice if there are some example codes in the huge gazebo API. For beginners like me, it's just all Greek. :(

**Comment by [SpiderRico](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/605/spiderrico/) on 2014-01-17**:
You are right. I hope these 2 tutorials will give you a nice start though :) Good luck.